# Error in using asIgraph() function in R to convert a network object to an igraph object?

Tags: r, igraph

I am currently trying to convert a network object to an igraph object. From various posts, I understand the `intergraph` package can do this through the `asIgraph()` function. I am trying to convert the classic Sampson dataset, which is found in the `ergm` package. When I do:

```
> library(ergm)
> library(intergraph)
> library(igraph)
> data(sampson)
> class(samplike) # The network object
[1] "network"
> asIgraph(samplike)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 88, 26
```

I have the error above. Does anyone have any idea why it fails for this canonical dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDIT**: See a recent post from two weeks ago on the `ergm` GitHub [Fixed the "nominations" attribute of the sampson
>   dataset.](https://github.com/statnet/ergm/commit/754c9e2dde37b909ed427df1501623f01fcc0531#diff-55cc757e02f4c7b27d6359dfdd201105)
>   This was an error in the sampson dataset that has now been fixed on
>   the GitHub version, but not yet updated to CRAN.

It's failing because the `sampson` dataset has an edge attribute `nominations` which only has 26 values even though there are 88 edges in the dataset. When `intergraph` tries to convert to `igraph` it attempts to bind the edge attributes to the edge list with `asDF()` and this step fails. The simple thing is to delete the edge attribute like so:

```
smplk<-samplike

delete.edge.attribute(smplk, "nominations")

asIgraph(smplk)

IGRAPH dca72f1 D--- 18 88 -- 
+ attr: cloisterville (v/l), group (v/c), na (v/l), vertex.names
| (v/c), na (e/l)
...
```

It's a little unclear to me from the documentation how this attribute *should* map on to the edgelist, but if this can be determined it could be added in separately with `set.edge.attribute`.